# Delphi Intraweb URL remove $

Tags: delphi, intraweb

In previous versions of [IntraWeb](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/index.en.aspx), an execute URL was signified by `/EXEC`, for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:25710/EXEC
```

In XI versions, this format is deprecated and any URL that maps valid IntraWeb content will be considered an execute URL. Until the new page features are implemented, the only URL is the root URL. For the example above, it would change to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:25710/$/EXEC
```

[read more...](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/blog/20100326.EN.aspx)

I do not like the URL will show the `/$/`. How can I remove it?

I prefer the old format

```
http://127.0.0.1:25710/EXEC
```

Comment: For future reference: IntraWeb 15 has a clean URL and doesn't need /EXEC nor /$